# Is it allowed to scale a matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a system matrix

$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 3 \\
-3 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The characteristic matrix is $K_A = A-\lambda I$ so it is

$$
K_A =
\begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda - 1 & 3 \\
-3 & -\lambda - 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

but am I allowed to set the following equal sign?:

$$
K_A=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda - 1 & 3 \\
-3 & -\lambda - 1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda + 1 & -3 \\
3 & \lambda + 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I have just multiplied the matrix with $-1$. Am I allowed to do so? To me the two matrices is not equal, so I guess I should use $\sim$ instead?

$$
K_A=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda - 1 & 3 \\
-3 & -\lambda - 1
\end{pmatrix}
\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda + 1 & -3 \\
3 & \lambda + 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: No, that is not allowed for a matrix. If you are looking for the determinant, and set it equal to zero, you can multiply by a nonzero constant from there.

Comment: Clearly the two matrices are not equal, as by definition two matrices are equal if and only if all their coefficients are equal. Then, what is the meaning for you of $A \sim B$ where $A,B$ are two matrices?

Comment: It should be clear that those two matrices are **not** equal. For example, the right top corner entry of one of them is $3$ while the corresponding entry in th other is $-3$: the two matrices are therefore diifferent!

Comment: On the other hand, is you plan to use $\sim$ then probably that means something to you. What, exactly? Whether it is correct to use that relation depends quite strongly on what that relation is, and we don't know! so we cannot tell.

Comment: @KittyL I'm not sure what your comment says but $\det(X)=0\iff\det(PXQ)$ for any conforming nonsingular $P$ and $Q$ including any kind of (elementary) row/column transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, given that you skip the first notation. The $\sim$ symbol is not standard when relating matrixes so you should be allowed to define that. Let's say $A\sim B$ means that $A = TB$ for $T$ in some group $G$ of matrices such that:

- $I \in G$
- if $T\in G$ then $T$ is invertible and $T^{-1}\in G$
- if $T_1\in G$ and $T_2\in G$ then $T_1T_2 \in G$

(for example the group of scaling matrices where the scale factor is non-zero fulfills these criteria, but there are larger groups, fx the group of invertible matrices)

Then $\sim$ will form an equivalence relation between matrices:

1. It's reflexive since $A=IA$ since the identity matrix is in the group.
2. It's symmetric since $A\sim B$ means that $A = T B$, but $T$ being in the group means that $T^{-1}$ being that to so $B = T^{-1}A$ (ie $B\sim A$)
3. It's transitive because if $A\sim B$ and $B\sim C$ we have $A = T_{AB}B$ and $B = T_{BC}C$ so $A = T_{AB}T_{BC}C$ where $T_{AB}T_{BC}$ is also in the group.

Now in each equivalence class under this relation either all matrices have zero determinant or all have non-zero determinant. If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices in the same class we have that $\det(A) = (\prod det{T_j})\det(B)$, but $\det{T_j} \ne 0$ always (rotations have determinant $1$ scaling has determinant $c^n$ where $c$ is the scaling factor and mirrorings have determinant $\pm 1$).

So $\det(A-\lambda I)=0 \Leftrightarrow \det(B)=0$ if $A\sim B$.

Another recent question suggested that two matrices should be called similar if $A = PBP^{-1}$, which also is a viable option (it's an equivalence relation and within each equivalence class either all determinants are zero or all determinants are non-zero, but doesn't include your transform).

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer:**
You can pull a factor out of the columns or rows. This still gives the same characteristic polynomial, so this is allowed.

To be safe, just write it with $| \ |$ around it and write the factor in front of it:
$$
\left|
\begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda - 1 & 3 \\
-3 & -\lambda - 1
\end{pmatrix}\right|
=-1\cdot \left|
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda + 1 & -3 \\
3 & \lambda + 1
\end{pmatrix}\right|
$$

**If you are interested in finding eigenvectors:**
$$K_A \vec v = \vec 0$$
You can do any operation which can be written by a multiplication with an **invertible** matrix from the left, since this doesn't change neither $\vec v$ nor the right side.
Here this would be multiplication with
$$ \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Arg, yes, of course. Thanks. =)